# Lazy loading. Why do I see the result of the JavaScript only when it is fully run through?

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of images on my page, and I am making lazy loading for them.
I use `img.onload = showmeup(img);` combination for all the images, but they all appear **simultaniusly**, when all are loaded, **not one after each other**.

Could you give me an advise, how to fix it to let them appears one after each other.

This is how I retrieve images from the server (It is WordPress BTW):

```
<div id="postbody" class="postcontent">
   <?php the_content();?>
</div>
```

This is the JS code:

```
<script>

var div = document.getElementById("postbody"),
    images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");

function showmeup(obg){
  obg.style.animationName = "showmeup";
}

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].onload = showmeup(images[i]);
}

</script>
```

Also I tired a more complicated way, using `if (images[i].complete) {}` to ensure that all images get processed apart:

```
<script>

var div = document.getElementById("postbody"),
    images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");

function showmeup(obg){
  obg.style.animationName = "showmeup";
}

var passed = [],
    ready = 0;

while (ready == 0){
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    if (images[i].complete && images[i].naturalHeight !== 0){
      if (passed.includes(i) == false){
        showmeup(images[i]);
        passed.push(i);
      }
    }
  }

  if (passed.length == images.length){
    ready = 1;
  }
}

</script>
```

But they still appear **simultaniusly** right after all images are loaded.

I tried to put JS code infront of `</body>` and into `<footer></footer>` and right after the `<?php the_content();?>`.
But all options work similary.

Please let me know how to fix it?

Comment: What's the code for loading the images and populating the `image` array? Do you actually make multiple http calls? My guess is that the issue isn't with how the images are displayed but how they're retrieved from the server

Comment: Hello @andyk, I've just updated the question and have added HTML and PHP. Please let me know if you have any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just to confirm: you know lazy image loading is [part of html](https://caniuse.com/?search=lazy), right? You just need `loading="lazy"` in your `<img>` tags. As is the [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), which you cam use to  remove the loading attribute "if the user's scroll position is close enough".

Comment: Hello @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thank you for your comment. Yes, but 1. In this case I lazy load not only images from `<?php the_content();?>` but also whole divs triggered by images loading. Divs are images and `<p>text</p>` above the images. 2. Not for this topic, but I don't know why,  `loading="lazy"` doen't always work. I don't have a clue why. 3. At the moment I don't know how to retrieve by PHP all images from `<?php the_content();?>`. I don't want to enter `loading="lazy"` manyally in WP panel every time when I make a new post.